# problem designating a bound for my sprite in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

i just got into game development and XNA and was following a tutorial and decided to try and add in a bound area for a floor. In the tutorial the sprite could move freely and i wanted to have a stopping point for it, so i added a statement to part of the input method

```
if (aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down) == true)
            {
                if (this.Position.Y == 420)
                {
                    MOVE_DOWN = 0;
                    mDirection.Y = MOVE_DOWN;
                }

                else
                {
                    mSpeed.Y = PLAYER_SPEED;
                    MOVE_DOWN = 1;
                    mDirection.Y = MOVE_DOWN;
                }


            }
```

MOVE_DOWN is my variable for the y change, if it = 0, there is no movement, 1 it moves down, -1 it moves up.
this worked only if the position of the bounds(420) was equal to the position that my sprite started out at, other than that it doesnt work.

i think its because the position isnt updating correctly. i dont know ive tried a lot of things and am pretty new with XNA and game development. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the update method for my player sprite

```
 public void Update(GameTime theGameTime)

    {

        KeyboardState aCurrentKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();



        UpdateMovement(aCurrentKeyboardState);




        mPreviousKeyboardState = aCurrentKeyboardState;



        base.Update(theGameTime, mSpeed, mDirection);

    }
```

and here is the update for the base class

```
public void Update(GameTime theGameTime, Vector2 theSpeed, Vector2 theDirection)
    {
        Position += theDirection * theSpeed * (float)theGameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything at all indicating that you are using a bounding box (or circle). If you could post the code for the bounding box movement, that would help a lot more.

Comment: i dont know if i used the correct terminology, but i just wanted a line that the sprite couldnt cross. a boundary at y = 420.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 'Position' is a Vector2, then it is using floats of the X & Y components.

For practical purposes, a float will rarely equal a whole number due to floating point rounding errors.

```
if (this.Position.Y == 420)//will never return true
```

should be changed to:

```
if (this.Position.Y < 420)
{
   this.Position = 420;
   //other stuff you have
}
```